# Filling out the FAQ-tag, professional style

Tags: discussion, sffaq

We need to fill in the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag. What we have in there is pretty minimal, and we need to find some questions that do a good job of covering some of the nuances of how things work around there.

So I ask you data-miners out there:

> What is the **best** meta-question that handles the issue of "...in a professional capacity"?

We've covered that one many times, do we have a question that does a good job of it? If so, what is it? Or do we need to hash it out again in a new question?

---

If we do get an answer to this question with a clear majority of upvotes, we'll go ahead and add the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag to the linked question.

Comment: We can probably also remove the [tag:faq] tag from things that have been addressed in the rewrite.

Comment: Also Related: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1760/server-fault-is-for-system-administrators-in-a-professional-capacity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Server Fault is for system administrators... in a professional capacity"](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1760/server-fault-is-for-system-administrators-in-a-professional-capacity)

I listed this question as "also related" since it contains an answer (by sysadmin1138 :) that links to a bunch of other answers.  I also feel the discussion in his answer and Womble's answer are pretty much the canonical definition of "in a professional capacity around here -- We might just want to change the title and use this as our definitive link.